# Is Patent US6194720B1 valid in France?

Tags: international

In reference to the patent: [US6194720](https://www.google.com/patents/US6194720)

Is that patent valid in France?

Answer (score 1):

US Patent grants are not directly enforceable worldwide. On the page you link to, you'll see an [Espacenet](http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/biblio?CC=US&NR=6194720B1&KC=B1&FT=D) link - that is a link to the EPO version of the patent, which will have the same description but usually a different set of claims. On that Espacenet page, look for the [Legal Status](http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/inpadoc?CC=US&NR=6194720B1&KC=B1&FT=D&ND=&date=20010227&DB=&&locale=en_EP) and [Patent Family](http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/inpadocPatentFamily?CC=US&NR=6194720B1&KC=B1&FT=D&ND=&date=20010227&DB=&locale=en_EP) links for foreign applications. Within the patent family I only see a single document - the US Patent grant US6194720 (B1), so it appears that no WIPO (worldwide, international) or EPO (European) application was filed. This means that the patent is only enforceable in the US.